# Unable to extrude SVG inside Blender

Tags: svg

I am using `Blender 2.8` with 20.04 Kubuntu. I have an SVG made using Inkscape 1.0 with 3 layers which I tried to import into Blender and `extrude` each layer with different heights. Sadly when going to `Edit mode` and trying the extrude option, I get almost zero results. Please see the image below. If possible, a helping hand will be great.

[image]

Answer (score 1):

Extruding vertices, edges or faces can only be done with meshes.
SVGs are by default Curves not mesh objects, a different kind of object, with different properties.

For 2d curves use the Geometry->Extrude options.

[image]

For further transformations you might need to convert the object to mesh. On the "Object" menu choose "Convert to" -> Mesh From Curve/Meta/Surf/Text.