# extrude / solidify bezier curve

Tags: bezier-curves

I have a closed bezier curve which forms a an area. This area should get thickness to become a tabletop.

I don't want to convert it to a mesh because I'm using the bezier curve to try out different shapes for that tabletop.

I tried to apply a solidify modifier but that did nothing.

So what are the steps needed?

Comment: Go to Properties Editor > Curve Properties Tab > Shape 2D > Fill mode Front or Both and Under Geometry > Extrude or Bevel ...

Comment: yes. worked. but hat to change type from 3d to 2d because it would only build the border but fill the area otherwise. thx!

Comment: Yes, that is what I wrote - 2D is the key :) Since 3D curve shape can become not flat there is no way how to create a surface.

Comment: https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/180866/unable-to-extrude-svg-inside-blender/180868#180868