# How to extrude an SVG on a cylinder but not have it solid

Tags: modeling

I have an SVG which is in the shape of a bone.

I need to have this shape wrap around a cylinder and have it extrude to have depth, however not be solid. Essentially a cookie cutter wrapped around a cylinder.

So far I've managed to import the SVG into Blender, that's as far as I've gotten. Most of the tutorials I see are about extruding a solid shape, but I'm not sure how to add thickness to the line of the bone and extrude from that.

Comment: Is your bone shape SVG solid-filled or an outline?

Comment: There should be various options in the curve geometry for this. Please upload your blend file or a downsized version of it.

Comment: It's just an outline. When I "covert to mesh" it is a series of points that make up a line of the bone shape.

Comment: If you are able to post the exact SVG, I could most likely provide a demo of how to do it.

Comment: See share link below for the bone SVG. Any help or pointers are appreciated. 
https://drive.google.com/file/d/1UZwZ3R7KRDY3Hy_xxm3CWG-Zck9ech9Q/view?usp=sharing

Comment: Do you actually intend to 3D print, and roll out accurate dog-biscuits with the result? The answers you've been given are fine for visualisation, (UV'd) ... but, strictly speaking, for that purpose, the bone should be deformed _in to_ a cylinder (by rotation) rather than projected _on to_ a cylinder (by translation), which might be  a bit trickier.

Comment: @RobinBetts yes I intend to do exactly that and my concern was exactly your point, that the resulting "bone" shape will be deformed when cut out.

Comment: How big are your biscuits? Do you want a roughly normal rolling-pin diameter?

Answer (score 2):

There is no need to convert the curve to mesh.

Start with the curve you imported.

[image]

Extrusion can be done in the curve's geometry section. To add some thickness use some bevel as well

[image]

Create a lattice object, make it so the resolution on the w axis is only one segment.

[image]

Use the lattice modifier on the curve, and have the lattice be the deforming object.

[image]

and then shrinkwrap the lattice to the cylinder.

[image]

Comment: Ah, a lattice! Good solution. I might try this with a W resolution of two and a target normal offset on the second layer to get the edges of the cookie cutter to face outward instead of up though.

Comment: See: [How to add a curve modifier to text](https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/33434/how-to-add-curve-modifier-to-text)

Answer (score 1):

[image]

### Preparation

Start by importing the svg and entering edit mode. Then, select two handles on opposite sides of the center and press <kbd>⇧ Shift</kbd><kbd>S</kbd> for the snapping pie menu. Drag the cursor down before releasing the keys to choose *Cursor to Selected.*

[image: cur to selected]

In object mode, press <kbd>W</kbd> or <kbd>[image: RMB] RMB</kbd> for the *Object Context Menu* and find *Origin to 3D Cursor.*

[image: orig to cur]

With the origin now correctly positioned, <kbd>⎇ Alt</kbd><kbd>G</kbd> will center the object in the scene.

Now convert the curve into a mesh via *Object Context Menu > Convert to Mesh*

[image: conv to mesh]

To clean up the mesh, delete all but one quadrant since it is symmetrical across two axes. I like to quickly press <kbd>X</kbd> followed by <kbd>V</kbd> (the underlined letter in the menu) to quickly delete vertices or edges, faces etc. by using their corresponding underlined letters.

[image: del verts]

The mesh has a ton of extra verts on this corner. Let's clean those up.

[image: bad corner]

Zoom in, select the unnecessary vertices and press <kbd>⎈ Ctrl</kbd><kbd>X</kbd> to dissolve them.

[image: oh no bad verts]

Also delete every other vertex in the denser area on the right. *Select > Checker Deselect* can speed this part up significantly.

[image: aaa more bad verts]

Now that the vertices are nicely distributed, the mesh can be symmetrized via *Mesh > Symmetrize.* Use the *Direction* settings *+X to -X* and *-Y to +Y* in either order.

Your mesh should now look like this:
[image: oooOOOooo aaaAAAaaa]

Press <kbd>F</kbd> to fill the interior of the shape then press <kbd>I</kbd> to inset the face, creating faces around the edge. Delete the large face to be left with just the outer face loop.

[image: outer loop]

Extrude this loop upward to the desired height with <kbd>E</kbd>.

[image: extrusion]

### Deformation

The shape can now easily be deformed across any surface by parenting it to a *Grid* mesh (*Add > Mesh > Grid*), adding a *Surface Deform* modifier with the grid as the target, and shrink-wrapping the grid to a cylinder, for example.

[image: weee we're done]

[image]

Comment: Note that you don't necessarily have to convert to mesh. Extrusion on a curve can be done in the geometry controls of the curve directly. see: https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/180866/unable-to-extrude-svg-inside-blender/180868#180868 and https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/193765/broken-text-after-text-being-extruded/193767#193767

Comment: the deformation works just fine with a curve.